# c# collection.RemoveAll(collection.OfType<type>());

Tags: c#, .net, collections, types, set

Can I do something like this:

```
collection.RemoveAll(collection.OfType<type>());
```

To remove all the elements of a given type from a collection?

Comment: What type of the collection object?

Comment: A type that "type" in the above example inherits from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>I would do something like this:</del>

<del>collection.RemoveAll(i => collection.OfType().Contains(i));</del>

---

EDIT:

```
 collection.RemoveAll(i => i is type);
```

Comment: @JeffN825, maybe he should write it in assembly?

Comment: Come on...I'm no performance maniac...just saying there are far more performant ways of writing this. In your example it literally loops through the entire collection for each item in the collection (n ^ 2 think...)...you could just do what George suggested and it's just as clean and simple. If you've got 1000 items, you're talking about making a million iterations instead of 1000.

Comment: Beware: If you use the `is` operator, you will remove objects whose type is *derived from* the specified type as well as those whose exact type *is* the specified type.

Comment: ty, presumably thats different from GetType..typeof that dosn't.

Comment: Makes sence though, for example "animal", subtype -> "cat". If it's an animal it's also a cat. Or "positionable" -> "box", same applies.

Comment: @alan2here *If it's an animal it's also a cat* I'd say the opposite : **if it's a cat, it's also an animal**. Have you ever heard of the aligator which was an animal so it was also a cat ?

Answer (score 10):

Both of the already-submitted answers are correct, but omit an explanation why the poster's sample code doesn't work.  A couple of interesting points:

First, `RemoveAll()` is not defined in the `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>` interface; it's defined on `List<T>`, for example, but the semantically equivalent method on `HashSet<T>` is called `RemoveWhere()`.  If you want to be able to do this for any  `ICollection<T>`, you should write an extension method.

Second, the question's sample code passes a sequence of items to be removed from the collection, but `List<T>.RemoveAll()` and `HashSet<T>.RemoveWhere()` take a predicate to identify the items to be removed (as shown in the other answers).  You could write your extension method to take the other approach, and pass an `IEnumerable<T>` as in your example.  You need to be careful, though, because you can't do this:

```
foreach (var item in collection)
    if (ShouldRemove(item))
        collection.Remove(item);
```

If you try to do that, you should get an `InvalidOperationException` with a message like "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

Comment: I +1 here because the question names the variable as "collection" and it clarifies a key point of ICollection<T> not having the RemoveAll or RemoveWhere method. It also points that the Remove within the foreach statement would not work. However, it should give a valid solution.

Comment: @IsaacLlopis Thanks for the upvote.  I did not give a valid solution for at least two reasons: (1) The answers that preceded mine were correct and (2) The question does not literally ask for a solution; it is a yes-or-no question.  I'm a firm believer in leaving things "as an exercise for the reader."  If the reader doesn't get it, he or she is free to ask for guidance.  (Like the other two answers, I inferred another question in addition to the explicit yes/no question.  The other answers infer "...and if not, what can I do to remove them?" while mine infers "...and if not, why not?")

Answer (score 4):

As the first two code answers use a List specifically, and the third only has nonworking code:

```
ICollection collection = GetCollection();
foreach (object obj in collection.Where(obj => obj is type).ToList())
     collection.Remove(obj);
```

You can end the enumeration by calling `ToList`, so that removal is allowed again. It's totally inefficient tho, as it requires one enumeration to get the objects and then removes them one by one, possibly requiring enumeration each time. If the collection type you're using has it's own methods, like `List.RemoveAll`, use those instead, but your use of "collection" implies you do not know its type.

Alternatively, if the importance is not on preserving the object, consider reassigning instead:

```
collection = collection.Where(obj => obj is type == false).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand it correctly, you have a single collection of any object type and you want to remove all items of a type from that collection.  If so, it's simple:

```
objects.RemoveAll(q=>q.GetType()==typeof(YourType));
```

Comment: Beware: if `YourType` is an interface, you won't remove any objects; similarly, if `YourType` is a base class, this approach will not remove instances of derived classes.

Comment: Thanks for the post, but I think Mike Stewart's revised answer is more concise as well as taking base derived classes into account, which would make sence.

Answer (score -3):

`collection.Clear()` removes all elements.

Comment: That's not what was asked though.